# Is it possible to reset your character and town name?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-blades

I rushed through the Elder Scrolls Blades intro and made some hasty naming decisions for my character and town. I would like to be able to rename them, even if it means starting from scratch. **Is it possible to rename your character and town names, or to wipe the game data and start over on the same account?**

After browsing the menus, I have not found any option to reset the game, and it seems as though the naming decisions I made are now linked to my Bethesda account. Based on this and the fact that I'm not getting any positive search results, I'm assuming the answer is no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible at this time to rename your character or town unless you create a new Bethesda account.

Comment: Looks like you're right. I just found the answer directly from the support site: "You can only create one character per account for The Elder Scrolls: Blades. Once a character is created it can not be deleted."  I guess I'll be stuck playing with a funny name then!